# sql query with an specific cardinality (many to many)

Tags: sql, count, mariadb

I have three tables in Mariadb

```
sensor
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name          | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| reload_time   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| discriminator | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

sensor_common_service
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| service_name  | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sensor_name   | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

common_service
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| service_name  | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| version       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| reload_time   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And I want to get all common_services that have exactly a set of sensors, for example, all common_services that have as sensors temperature and humidity.

So, if I have

```
common_service1 : sensors [temperature]
common_service2 : sensors [temperature,humidity]
common_service3 : sensors [temperature,humidity, luminosity]
```

The query should return only common_service2.

My first attemp was trying to adapt the queries on [Join between mapping (junction) table with specific cardinality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170101/join-between-mapping-junction-table-with-specific-cardinality)

And this is the result

```
SELECT * FROM custom_service
JOIN (
      SELECT scm.service_name FROM sensor_custom_service scm
      WHERE scm.sensor_name IN (
                      SELECT s.name FROM sensor s
                      WHERE s.name='luminosity' OR s.name='temperature'
                      )
      GROUP BY scm.service_name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT scm.sensor_name)=2
      ) AS jt
ON custom_service.service_name=jt.service_name;
```

another one,

```
SELECT scs.* FROM sensor_custom_service scs
where scs.sensor_name IN ( 'luminosity', 'temperature' )
GROUP BY scs.service_name;
HAVING COUNT(scs.sensor_name) = 2
```

But with this queries I also get the common_services that have other sensors
since the having count is only counting the sensor_custom_service that meets the where clause.

Using the above example this queries both return

```
common_service2 : sensors [temperature,humidity]
common_service3 : sensors [temperature,humidity]
```

I think that this query would be easy using INTERSECT operator with sth like this

```
SELECT scs.* FROM sensor_custom_service scs
where scs.sensor_name IN ( 'luminosity', 'temperature' )
INTERSECT
SELECT scs.* FROM sensor_custom_service scs
HAVING COUNT(scs.sensor_name) = 2
```

but Mariabb returns

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT
```

because it isn't supported ( I think, because both queries works individually)

---

Solution using 9000's query.

```
select * 
from custom_service cs 
where 
  exists (select 1 from sensor_custom_service scs where 
      scs.service_name = cs.service_name and
      scs.sensor_name = 'luminosity') 
  AND
  exists (select 1 from sensor_custom_service scs where 
      scs.service_name = cs.service_name and
      scs.sensor_name = 'temperature')
  AND
  NOT exists (select  1  from sensor_custom_service scs where
      scs.service_name = cs.service_name and
      scs.sensor_name NOT IN ('temperature', 'luminosity'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB and MySQL have the GROUP_CONCAT() function to accomplish this task:

```
SELECT service_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(sensor_name ORDER BY sensor_name) AS sensors
FROM sensor_common_service
GROUP BY service_name
HAVING sensors='humidity,temperature'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f574/1

Answer (score 1):

Note that `IN` gives you an `OR` semantics when you need an `AND` semantics. Basically if you need all 3 sensors present, you need 3 joins, each representing a separate sensor. Something along the lines of

```
select * 
from common_service cs 
where 
  exists (select 1 from sensor_common_service scs where 
          scs.service_name = cs.service_name and
          scs.sensor_name = 'luminosity') 
  AND
  exists (select 1 from sensor_common_service scs where 
          scs.service_name = cs.service_name and
          scs.sensor_name = 'temperature')
  -- add more sensors along these lines
```

This also means that it's impossible to write a variadic query that works for any number of sensors. (I'd love to be proved wrong!)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 

Your query produce the same results as long as it only checks if the custom_service has those sensors but not if it has more.

Although you point me in the right direction and finally I achieved it adding a few lines to your query. I'm going to update the answer with the solution because it's too long to put it here.

Thank you, you saved my day!

Comment: Good to hear this! Alas, you have to add as many `exists()` lines as many sensors you have to check.

Answer (score 1):

All you want to do is count the number of times 'Temperature' and 'Humidity' show up and the number of times anything else shows up per service. The results should be when the first number = 2 (both show up) and the second number = 0 (nothing else shows up).

```
select  ss.Service_Name
from    Sensor_Service ss
group by ss.Service_Name
having  Sum( case when ss.Sensor_Name in( 'Temperature', 'Humidity' ) then 1 else 0 end ) = 2
    and Sum( case when ss.Sensor_Name in( 'Temperature', 'Humidity' ) then 0 else 1 end ) = 0;
```

This uses just generic SQL. I tested it on Oracle and MariaDB. It should run as-is on most others.